# react import image from server during run time

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file, multer

I'm trying to allow a user to upload an image to a server and then display the image on the client after the upload is complete. I'm struggling to get the `<img src= />` to reference the correct path. I'm building the app with webpack and trying to get it to work in both dev and production environments.

My simplified folder structure is:

```
|-- files
|  uploadedImage.jpg
|--dist
|  index.html
|  main.js
|--src
|    --Components
|      InputComponent.js
|server.js
```

I'm using Multer to handle the upload. I save the file to the files folder and then save the filename to a MongoDB document for the user. Once this is done I update my redux store with the filename and pass it into the component. I am trying to load the image into my react component by referencing the filename in the files folder.

Am I missing something in the webpack build? I figured that's not the issue because the upload occurs after the app is built. Do I just need a reference to the `files` folder? I'm not exactly sure how to do that because the folder is outside the react app/browser.

Comment: Actually, you need a different NodeJS app for handling images server for uploading. your question is not related to ReactJS and your bundle or webpack issue.

Comment: Are you able to get a ``src`` route? Can you check the console for the expected HTTP error?

Comment: Ah ok, so I essentially just need to access the file through a web-server.